# How can I allow a user to bookmark a Facebook app with a button/hyperlink click?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I'm having a real hard time keeping up with Facebook's ever-changing platform.

Does any one have a solution to allowing a user to bookmark the app that I'm developing with either a hyperlink click or button click (so I guess some sort of JavaScript handler)? Or is it no longer possible?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://labnol.blogspot.com/2006/01/add-to-favorites-ie-bookmark-firefox.html) might solve your problems !